# Are all functions mappings between sets?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I am trying to better understand what a function *is*.

I often see diagrams with two ovals with a bunch of lines between them, and I believe these represent sets, but I don't know if there's an official name for this, nor if this is how all functions behave.

Would it be accurate to say that a set is just a collection of objects without duplicates, and that a function is a mapping between "input" objects of one set and "output" objects of another set, such that each input is related to exactly one output object?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.  More formally, we might treat a function as a subset of the cartesian product $X\times Y$ where $X$ is our "domain" (*set of inputs*) and $Y$ is our "codomain" (*set of possible outputs*) such that every element in the domain appears *exactly* once as the first entry in an ordered pair.  In that case we actually have a function $f$ being of the form something like $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),\dots\}$.  For shorthand we usually rewrite $(x_1,y_1)\in f$ as instead $f(x_1)=y_1$.

Comment: Note: no such requirement is placed on the elements from the codomain.  Those functions which do happen to have every element in the codomain appearing at least once each, or at most once each are given a special name: surjective and injective functions respectively or bijective if both.

Comment: @JMoravitz So the "cartesian product" is also a set, since we're writing things like $(x_1, y_1) \in f$? How would this correspond to writing the function as something like $f(x) = x^2$ or something? Is this another way of writing it or a transformation on the set notation in some form?

Comment: And what would be the "full" way of writing the function if we wished to be thorough? Like does it make sense to say $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, f(x) = x^2$ to fully describe an integer-squarer? Or what if we wished to specify the domain? For example all reals except $3$ or something?

Comment: Writing $f(x)=x^2$ is shorthand for saying we're referring to the function $f\subseteq X\times Y$ such that $f=\{(x,x^2)~:~x\in X\}$.  People almost exclusively think using the shorthand version though, and generally only use the formal definition when first teaching or learning the formal definition of functions.  The integer squarer function could be written $f~:~\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ s.t. $f(x)=x^2$, or it could be written $f\subseteq \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ s.t. $f = \{(x,x^2)~:~x\in \Bbb Z\}$ or some other variation.

Comment: A minor frustration when it comes to being rigorous, not only is the rule for how inputs are changed into outputs important for a function, but the domain and codomain are also important for adequately describing the function.  Note for example $f~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ s.t. $f(x)=x^2$ is neither injective nor surjective.  Meanwhile $f~:~\Bbb N\to \Bbb Z$ s.t. $f(x)=x^2$ is injective but not surjective.  Finally $f~:~\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^+$ s.t. $f(x)=x^2$ is both injective and surjective.

Comment: Does it matter whether it's injective, surjective, etc? Is that some necessary requirement? I'm not sure I understand what this last comment is saying.

Comment: It matters, for example, when you are interested in the inverse of a function. Consider finding $f^{-1}$ in the three scenarios given by JMoravitz. With $f:\Bbb {Z\to Z}$, we have two reasons why $f^{-1}$ cannot exist: $f$ is not injective: $f(-3)=f(3)=9$, so the meaning of $f^{-1}(9)$ would be ambiguous; next, $f$ is not surjective: there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=8$, so it would be nonsense to write $f^{-1}(8)$. The restriction $f:\Bbb {N\to Z}$ solves the first of these problems. Finally, if $f:\Bbb {R^+\to R^+}$, then $f^{-1}$ is well defined (and we could call it $\sqrt x$).

Comment: So inverse functions can only exist if the original function is bijective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation of functions is clear and correct.

A function has three ingredients: Domain, Range,and Assignment.

Domain is the set of inputs, Range is the set of outputs and assignment is a formula or table which tells you what goes to what.

And as you mentioned we do not want to send the same input to two different outputs.

We can have graphs,tables, definitions, or any other way to represent functions.
Examples of real world functions are social security numbers assigned to people, birthdays, age, and so fort.